Does using a range with unreachable_sentinel lead to undefined behaviour?
Cppreference has the following example of the usage of std::unreachable_sentinel:
template<class CharT>
constexpr std::size_t strlen(const CharT* s)
{
    return std::ranges::find(s, std::unreachable_sentinel, CharT{}) - s;
}

However, the standard states in [iterator.requirements.general]:

A sentinel s is called reachable from an iterator i if and only if there is a finite sequence of applications of the expression ++i that makes i == s. If s is reachable from i, [i, s) denotes a valid range.
… [skipping the paragraph about counted ranges, not applicable here] …
The result of the application of library functions to invalid ranges is undefined.

Does this really mean that the above code has undefined behaviour (even in cases where the input string is zero-terminated), and if so, in what context can std::unreachable_sentinel be legally used then?

N.b. there is a very similar example in the standard char* nl = find(p, unreachable_sentinel, '\n');

Yes, the standard says that infinite ranges are invalid (the italics in that quote is significant: it indicates that this is the definition of the term valid range). And yes, passing invalid ranges to library functions is undefined, as the quote says. And yet it also provides a number of infinite ranges.
Basically, getting infinite ranges right is hard, which is why they are not included in the current ranges design in the standard. (range-v3 tries to solve this with its "cardinality" design, but it's not clear if even its authors like it.) But some infinite ranges are undeniably useful, so the standard pragmatically included them, even though they don't fit in the current model.

So infinite ranges are "not included in the current ranges design in the standard" but it also provides a number of them? What does this mean?

@Useless it means the standards committee didn't want to bother pinning down definitions of how everything should behave.

Explicitly defining a facility provided by the standard library itself as invalid seems like more work, not less.

I can't be correct that both

s being reachable from i is the [only] way for [i, s) to be a valid range, and that the
result of the application of [all] library functions to invalid ranges is undefined.

Taken at face value,

[iterator.requirements.general]/8 which says

A range is an iterator and a sentinel that designate the beginning and end of the computation, or an iterator and a count that designate the beginning and the number of elements to which the computation is to be applied)

would not be able to permit unbounded computations (ie, either this should be considered a valid range, or the application of some library functions to this invalid range should be OK)

std::ranges::iota_view, when defaulting to unreachable_sentinel_t for its upper bound, should either constitute a valid range, or an invalid range to which some library functions can nevertheless be applied

std::ranges::repeat_view likewise, and so on


Next, we see that some library functions explicitly require valid ranges, and some don't.

ranges::rotate and rotate_copy are the first algorithms explicitly to require valid input ranges.
none of the prior mutating sequence operations (copy, move, transform, ..., unique) which operate on input or forward iterators have similar language. I'm ignoring those requiring bidirectional or random-access iterators or ranges, as those wouldn't be satisfied by unreachable_sentinel anyway.

So we have some grounds for believing that at least some library functions should be applicable to unbounded ranges.
Whether that's because unbounded ranges are not invalid, or because some library functions may be applied to unbounded ranges despite being invalid, is unclear.
